# SBS 2008 automatically adds additional subnet 192.168.0.2/24 on every reboot

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I have SBS 2008 and the LAN is using a 10.1.1.0/24 subnet. The server has an IP of 10.1.1.2/24 and the clients are on a DHCP range of 10.1.1.10-254/24.

When I open Network Connections (ncpa.cpl), right click the LAN adapter and go to Status, it says the server IP is 10.1.1.2.

However if I go into the adapter and click into the IPv4 settings, it says:

```
IP:      192.168.0.2
Subnet:  255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.1.1.5
DNS:     10.1.1.2
```

If I go into the advanced settings, I can see 2 IP addresses but only the one Gateway and DNS. If I remove the 192.168.0.2 address, SBS prompts for a reboot. After the reboot, the 192.168.0.2 address is still there.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP/IP stack might be corrupted and the solution could be to reset it. This Microsoft KB article

[How to reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;299357)

explains how to do this.

Essentially, you'll have to execute the following command in a command prompt:

```
netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
```

Reboot the server and re-configure the IP address.

If you have other network cards/configurations, make sure you jot down the addresses, subnet masks etc. before you reset the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go this weekend when we're able to have some downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun the "Connect to the internet" wizard. You'll find it as the second task in the SBS Console.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go this weekend when we're able to have some downtime.